# How to prompt execution`s status of a shell command in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I'm looking for a way to print in a webpage the status of the execution of a shell command.
Using NodeJS and a module called sudo-js I execute a command that in shell prints the status of the execution, the problem is that I just print all the progress at the end of the execution in the website, but I would like to print that in real time as in shell terminal into the webpage.

Here is my code

```
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack); 
          } else {
            var command = ['ansible-playbook', '-i', 'hosts.txt', 'sample.yaml'];
            sudo.exec(command, function(err, pid, result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.render('mensajeScriptEjecutadoConResultado', {Resultado: result});
            });

          }
        })
```

I know that console.log() doesn't work in showing data by buffer or in real time, and sudo.exe() may not work like this too, so how to do that?.

Thank you!.

Comment: You need to use server push or WebSockets to have continuous feedback between the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module, which includes some helpful examples.  Your node program can react to standard output, error and process completion.

I use this to report the current status of a child process to web clients... but I didn't make it continuous like @Barmar mentions; my client has to refresh to get the status.